# Unable to access the admin section of my Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the URL of the site I am referring to: http://www.nagorik.org/
The site seems to be working fine.

However, when I am trying to access the admin site through http://www.nagorik.org/wp-login.php, I get the following message in Firefox:

*Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.*

Any idea why this might be happening?

Some notes:

1. I checked the error log file; nothing new in it.
2. I have nagorik.org redirecting to www.nagorik.org

Comment: you need to check your database, what is the site_url in the wp_options table. Maybe that is nagorik.org, and when go the the admin panel, then wp try to redirect to nagorik.org, what is redirect to www... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete. **This problem can
>   sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.**

Let's try to check the cookie settings to see if it helps.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is you're missing a ton of Wordpress files in /wp-admin/. You might want to consider reinstalling wordpress or at least re-uploading the /wp-admin/ directory.

Comment: Fixing your issue or not, it's quite important that all the wordpress files be there. I would check the rest of the installation for missing files.